# PuTTY and Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, putty

I recently needed to access a Windows machine with Windows Remote Desktop, but I was unable to connect due to a firewall on the network. (While on the network, I have successfully connected to the system). The only way to connect to the network is through SSH.

How do I configure PuTTY to SSH into a remote network and then allow me to use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a machine on that network?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set up port forwarding.

To do this, do the following:

- Go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels in the configuration
- Choose some source port which is not used on your system; I tend to choose something like 13389
- For destination enter the IP address or the host name of the system you want to connect to with RDP, followed by ":3389"
- Local and Auto can stay as they are
- Click "Add" to add the forwarding to the list of forwarded ports
- You can save your configuration if you need it more often

[image: Screenshot of PuTTY showing an example configuration]

Now you can connect to your network. After the SSH connection is established you can use the Remote Desktop Connection to connect to "localhost:13389" (the port at the end must match the local port you selected in PuTTY). You should connect to the remote computer, then.

Comment: Remember to click "add", to add your new rule to the list of forwarded ports, before clicking "open" or going to a different configuration tab. The amount of times I forget this and have to go back to re-enter a rule is embarrassing.

Comment: Eep, you're right. Added this to the explanation.

Comment: and then "save" in "Session" category

Comment: Cool. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Occasionally, Windows decides that you can't remote desktop to "localhost". You can use "127.0.0.2" instead.