# Connecting to remote desktop from windows through ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop

I am sitting on a Windows computer, on a network, that doesn’t allow me to connect to a Windows server outside the network on RDP - however I am able to SSH into a third server outside the network.

Is it possible to make a remote desktop connection through my ssh server, so I can get the Windows server remote desktop on my Windows computer?

Answer (score 0):

From a Linux Host you Open a Terminal and connect using the folowing command.

```
ssh -X [ipaddr]
```

then you can use graphically aplications and use your preferred RDP client for example [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)

being more clear that will allow you to connect graphically with RDP client from that host located inside your current area network.

If the OS from the host using SSH client is Windows you should fordward the X server and should have a Windows X Session software as [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

In PuTTY X11 Fordwarding can be enabled in

Conection > SSH > X11 and mark *Enable X11 fordwarding*

[image]

> **Prerequisites.**

- Remote Linux host must be running a X server.
- You should have a good bandwidth conection.

Comment: I think this would be better accomplished using the `Tunnels` option right below `X11` in the putty UI. SSH to outside server to tunnel a port to RDP server and port.

Comment: @ssnobody i dont know whats that options does, explain us in an answer

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/881099/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-with-putty-to-connect-neo4j-database (To fixup, replace destination IP (shown as `localhost` with remote RDP server IP and replace destination port (shown as `7474`) with `3389`

Comment: The `-X` and `-Y` options for SSH are for X11 forwarding.  The questioner needs IP forwarding, using `-L`

Answer (score 0):

As @ssnobody pointed out in the comment, Tunnels are better suited for this problem.

Check this [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/43918/putty-and-remote-desktop) question out which details the exact same thing you want to accomplish ( so much so I think this question might be a duplicate )

Or, Follow these steps.

- Go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels in the configuration
- Choose some source port which is not used on your system; I tend to choose something like 13389 For destination enter the IP address or the host name of the system you want to connect to with RDP, followed by
  ":3389"
- Local and Auto can stay as they are
- Click "Add" to add the forwarding to the list of forwarded ports
- You can save your configuration if you need it more often

[image: PuTTy using rdp over ssh]

Now you can connect to your network. After the SSH connection is established you can use the Remote Desktop Connection to connect to "localhost:13389" (the port at the end must match the local port you selected in PuTTY). You should connect to the remote computer, then.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/43918/putty-and-remote-desktop)

Edit: added link. Thanks Donald Duck for pointing that out.

Comment: Which superuser question?

Answer (score -1):

It depends a bit on the bandwidth of you connection whether RDP works as you would like.

But technically you can use SSH port forwarding (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) to forward the relevant ports for RDP, so that you can connect to the other server via RDP over your SSH connection.

Comment: Consider reproducing the relevant text from the link that would accomplish the OP's task. If the link goes down or changes, this answer isn't very useful.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer Links to external resources are encouraged @ssnobody is right.